# Is there a well-defined way to check if a path is a simple file/folder name in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems

I'm trying to check if a given user-supplied string is a simple file/folder name. I plan on using os.path.join() to concatenate this name to a preset root directory, but I want to detect and prohibit paths that try to traverse anywhere outside of that root directory.

For example, a string with the value 'track001.mp3' would be fine, it would resolve to 'root_dir/track001.mp3'. However, these should be detected and disallowed:

```
'../other_root_dir/'
'/etc'
'/'
'~'
'subdir/inner_file'
```

Comment: you can use `os.path.listdir` to list whatever is acceptable and cross verify or did i not understand your question?

Comment: Why would `~` be unacceptable? That's only a metacharacter when unquoted in the shell; it's a literal tilde anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to create the path string as you normally would *assuming* that the user is behaving (e.g. passing a "simple" or conforming path name).  Then I'd use [`os.path.expandvars`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) and [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to get the actual path name.  Finally, I'd check to make sure that the actual path name resides within the root directory.  Something like:

```
from os.path import expandvars, normpath, join

ROOT_DIR = 'root_dir'

user_path = 'some_path'
test_path = normpath(expandvars(join(ROOT_DIR, user_path)))

expected_prefix = normpath(ROOT_DIR)
if not test_path.startswith(expected_prefix):
    raise ValueError(f'Invalid path "{user_path}"')  # python3.6 f-string.
```